# I am unable to get output with this uni exercise, all functions individually work but together give empty output

Tags: list, haskell, output

So, I have this uni exercise, which works all fine, untill I hand it in through domjudge. Then I get a run error on run 1, 3 and 4, while run 2 works fine. The error info says it has to do with a non exhaustive pattern in function printTable : []

But when I add in printTable [] = [] in an attempt to fix it, runs 1, 3 and 4 have no output, probably due to going through the function with the above rule.

I know you guys don't have much information on the runs, but what I find so weird is that in run 2 it is fine, while having problems in all other runs. Help me please ?

Code: http://pastebin.com/gAyWWQJJ

EDIT: Some more information on the input and output:

in and output: http://pastebin.com/TLJ5MfjL

gotten output:
[]

yes, an empty list.

as you might have seen in the code, it maps words to the [String] it reads from this, so you get [[String]]. then Field = String, Row = [Field] and Table = [Row] = [[Field]] - [[String]].

The input for run 2 should be similar to the one of run 1, but for some reason which I cannot for the love of god find out, run 2 works fine and run 1 doesn't.

I hope to have supplied enough information, because this is really all I have.

Comment: Put your code in the question, not in a link. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right:

```
select :: Field -> Field -> Table -> Table
select _ _ [] = []
select column _ table = table
select column value table@(header:rows)
    = maybe table (\x -> filter (\y -> (!!) y x == value) rows) (elemIndex column header)
...
```

The result of `select x y table` will *always* be `table` - i.e. it always returns the entire table.

Besides, if you run `ghc -Wall program.hs` you'll get this morning:

```
db.hs:108:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In an equation for ‘select’:
        select column value table@(header : rows) = ...
```

which basically says that the last clause for `select` will never be used.